# CUDA and Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RC

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

Just finished installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 (RC). I previously had configured and got working the cuda development toolkit 7.5. After updating VS I was prompted to install an update for NVIDIA nsight (a newer version of NSIGHT 5).

When all this was done the "New project" page had "lost" the option to create an Nvidia project and wasn't even able to (correctly) open CUDA sample solutions. Is there a known issue on this or something I could do to overcome it ?

I'm using VS 2015 community on Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS 2015 is not supported currently by CUDA 7.5 or any CUDA toolkit.

If you want to have a properly installed CUDA 7.5 environment so that you can open and build CUDA projects, you will need to use VS 2013, until such time in the future as VS 2015 is supported.

Note that nsight VSE is a tool that can be used independently of CUDA, and it *does* have support for VS 2015, which is why you were prompted to install the update for that tool.

But VS 2015 is not supported currently for CUDA development work.  The supported platforms for **CUDA 7.5** are listed [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements).  VS2013 is supported.  VS2015 is not.

nsight Visual Studio edition supports VS2015

CUDA 7.5 does **not** support VS2015

Comment: You could keep both VS2013 and VS2015, then install Nsight 5.0 and work in VS2015, but using VS2013 toolset.